# Trace function did not show the steps to the final answer

Tags: symbolic

```
Trace[
 FullSimplify[
  1/4 Sec[20 °] + Sin[10 °] + 2 Sin[10 °]^2
 ]
]
```

*Mathematica* gave the correct answer 1/2, but it did not show the final steps to arrive at 1/2.  Why?

Comment: `Trace` shows the intermediate expressions generated when evaluating its argument, not the internal transformations performed by the individual functions. This is pretty much by design. Otherwise you could, for example, peep into proprietary implementations of certain algorithms (which MMA does not want to disclose).

Comment: Thanks.  Would MMA make Mathematica show the name of transformations that have been taken but not the algorithms that have been implemented to carry out the transformations ?  Maybe, I have asked too much because what group of transformations the have been performed is also a secret.

Comment: Add optioni `TraceInternal->True` to your `Trace` command and you will get GIANT amount of internal transformations to reach the result. But is not of much use for ordinary users.